# Automapper in xUnit testing and .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit

I have .NET Core 2.0 Project which contains Repository pattern and xUnit testing.

Now, here is some of it's code.

**Controller:**

```
public class SchedulesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IScheduleRepository repository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public SchedulesController(IScheduleRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Schedule>, IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>>(source: repository.items);
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
}
```

**My Test Class:**

```
public class SchedulesControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanGet()
    {
        try
        {
            //Arrange
            Mock<IScheduleRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IScheduleRepository>();
            mockRepo.Setup(m => m.items).Returns(new Schedule[]
            {
                new Schedule() { Id=1, Title = "Schedule1" },
                new Schedule() { Id=2, Title = "Schedule2" },
                new Schedule() { Id=3, Title = "Schedule3" }
            });

            var mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
            mockMapper.Setup(x => x.Map<Schedule>(It.IsAny<ScheduleDto>()))
                .Returns((ScheduleDto source) => new Schedule() { Title = source.Title });

            SchedulesController controller = new SchedulesController(repository: mockRepo.Object, mapper: mockMapper.Object);

            //Act
            var result = controller.Get();

            //Assert
            var okResult = result as OkObjectResult;
            Assert.NotNull(okResult);

            var model = okResult.Value as IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>;
            Assert.NotNull(model);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Assert
            Assert.False(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue I Am facing.**

My Issue is that when I run this code with database context and execute `Get()` method, it works fine, it gives me all results.

But when I tries to run test case, it's not returning any data of Dto object.
When I debugged I found that

1. I am getting my test object in controller using `mockRepo`.
2. But it looks like Auto mapper is not initialized correctly, because while mapping it's not returning anything in

   `var result = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Schedule>, IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>>(source: repository.items);`

**What I tried So Far?**

I followed all this answers but still it's not working.

[Mocking Mapper.Map() in Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984530/mocking-mapper-map-in-unit-testing)

[How to Mock a list transformation using AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605470/how-to-mock-a-list-transformation-using-automapper)

So, I need help from someone who is good in xUnit and automapper, and need guidance on how to initialize mock Mapper correctly.

Comment: You seem to be using a different signature of Map in your code and your moq setup. Instead of mocking Map<dest> try mocking the Map<source, dest> method instead.

Comment: @jcemoller finally it worked without mocking, I just created mapper object and injected it with my profile.

Comment: @Bharat was writing that up as an answer when you left your comment. No need for me to do it now. You can add it as a self answer to your question. Here is a similar answer I provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864288/problems-in-creating-unit-test-for-asp-net-mvc/39868221#39868221. Note it is using a different mocking framework but the automapper part is applicable.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, I fixed this issue and it's working fine,I Posted my answer but there is one another tricky issue, which I am trying to resolve from the morning, I think I will need your help over there.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Finally it worked for me, I followed this way [How to Write xUnit Test for .net core 2.0 Service that uses AutoMapper and Dependency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708895/how-to-write-xunit-test-for-net-core-2-0-service-that-uses-automapper-and-depen?rq=1)

Here I am posting my answer and Test Class so if needed other SO's can use.

```
public class SchedulesControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanGet()
    {
        try
        {
            //Arrange
            //Repository
            Mock<IScheduleRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IScheduleRepository>();
            var schedules = new List<Schedule>(){
                new Schedule() { Id=1, Title = "Schedule1" },
                new Schedule() { Id=2, Title = "Schedule2" },
                new Schedule() { Id=3, Title = "Schedule3" }
            };

            mockRepo.Setup(m => m.items).Returns(value: schedules);

            //auto mapper configuration
            var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
            });
            var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();

            SchedulesController controller = new SchedulesController(repository: mockRepo.Object, mapper: mapper);

            //Act
            var result = controller.Get();

            //Assert
            var okResult = result as OkObjectResult;
            if (okResult != null)
                Assert.NotNull(okResult);

            var model = okResult.Value as IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>;
            if (model.Count() > 0)
            {
                Assert.NotNull(model);

                var expected = model?.FirstOrDefault().Title;
                var actual = schedules?.FirstOrDefault().Title;

                Assert.Equal(expected: expected, actual: actual);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Assert
            Assert.False(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to inject `IMapper`, use `ProjectTo` to get a mapped `IQueryable`, then implement some more logic on the queryable after the map. So here's what I did to mock it:

```
var models = new object[]
{
    ⋮
}.AsQueryable();
var mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapper.Setup(x => x.ProjectTo(
        It.IsAny<IQueryable>(),
        It.IsAny<object>(),
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<object, object>>[]>()))
    .Returns(models);
```